# wordpress error，Undefined offset: 1 in /srv/www/mywork/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php on line 6284

Tags: wordpress

I builted my blog with wordpress.recently,my blog can't access. i check the nginx error log:

```
016/02/17 21:49:56 [error] 27909#0: *8303029 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 185.130.5.209, server: localhost, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
then ,i checked zhe wordpress log:
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /srv/www/zhk1/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php on line 6284
```

I did not modify zhe file class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php.
Can anybody can help me ?

Comment: What were you doing just before it broke? The file `/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html` handles server level error pages.

Comment: i changed my theme,i seemed fine at that time.

Comment: What is the name of the theme you change to? So the site went down when you activated the new theme?

Comment: Try renaming the specific theme folder with your FTP client to get your admin panel back. Then activate a different theme. I would then contact the theme developer.

Comment: when i changed the theme,the site was ok. i can not access the site after a few days . i will try to renaming the specific theme folder to get my admin panel back. thank you

Comment: i have renamed my theme folder in the path /wp-content/themes/ ,but the site still can not access ..

Comment: Next thing I would try is commenting out lines 6283 and 6284 in `class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php` which read `if ( !$linea ) return $this->pingback_error( 16, __( 'The source URL does not exist.' ) );`

Comment: i recreated my database,it can work but i lost all my blog